# creating multiple files from template and replace content on-the-fly

Tags: linux, bash, sed, nagios, icinga

As stated in the title i'd like to create multiple files from a template and replace a fixed keyword on-the-fly

if i do

```
$ sed s/XX/{01..05}/g templates/pXX.conf
```

i get kinda close, since i get an correct output for first result, but an error for numbers 02-04.

since it's not neccessary in icinga to separate each configuration file (but it would be a bonus), it's ok to get the result into a single output-file.

Example:

```
//template.conf
object Host "pXX" {
  display_name = "RasPi XX"
  ...
}
```

this now should result into:

```
//p01.conf <- ascending filenames would be a bonus
object Host "p01" {
  display_name = "RasPi 01"
  ...
}
//p02.conf
object Host "p02" {
  display_name = "RasPi 02"
  ...
}
// and so on
```

i'm pretty sure this is easy done by using any sort of script with a loop inside

```
while $i < number: read file; replace content; output file;
```

i'm just curious if this can be done using some single line commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in 01 02 03; do sed "s/XX/$i/" template.conf > template$i.conf; done
```

Comment: works. sweet! ("for i in {01..99}" makes it scaleable, tho)

Comment: @EBZ-Krisemendt: A very good point -- although one must be careful with the leading '0'.